# inserting to sql from textfield and textarea doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

please help, inserting datas from my textfields combined with my textareas to db not working,

please help on how to combine my VALUES properly. I cant seem to figure out how to combine the implode for my textareas and the other values from textfields.

below is my PHP code:

```
$Category2 = $_POST['Category2'];
    $Category3 = $_POST['Category3'];
    $Status = $_POST['Status'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date'];
    $Severity = $_POST['Severity'];
    $BanType = $_POST['BanType'];
    $XiD = $_POST['XiD'];
    $Ticket = $_POST['Ticket'];

    //Process the input textareas into arrays
    $PhoneNumber = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode("\n", $_POST['PhoneNumber']));
    $Createdate = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode("\n", $_POST['Createdate']));
    $RemedyTicketNo = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode("\n", $_POST['PhoneNumber']));

    //Determine the values with the least amoutn of elements
    $min_count = min($PhoneNumber, $Createdate, $RemedyTicketNo);

    //Create array to hold INSERT values
    $values = array();

    //Create the INSERT values
    for($index=0; $index<$min_count; $index++)
    {
    $values[] = "('$RemedyTicketNo[$index]','$PhoneNumber[$index]','$Createdate[$index]',
'$Category2','$Category3','$Status','$Date','$Severity','$BanType','$XiD')";     
    }

    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT into tbl_main
    (ars_no,phone_number,create_date,category_1,category_2,status,resolved_date,trouble_type_priority,ban_type,employee_id_name)
    VALUES " . implode (',',$values));
if (!$sql) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
    header("Location: smp_backend_test.php");
    }
```

here is my html code: this has the textfields,

```
<td colspan="2"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateDBLoad()">
          <table width="435" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="115"><div align="left" style="font-size:12px"></div></td>
              <td width="167" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="139" align="right"><input type="reset" name="Clear" id="Clear" value="Clear" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="24" style="font-size:12px"><strong>Ticket Source:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2"><select name="Ticket" id="Ticket">
                <option value="tickettracker.php">Please select...</option>
                <option value="wireless_new.php">Wireless - Remedy</option>
                <option value="smp_backend_test.php" selected="selected">SMP - Backend</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="24" style="font-size:12px"><strong>Date:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2">
                <label for="datepickerID"></label>
                <input type="text" name="Date" id="Date" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>XiD, Name:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2"><span style="font-size:12px">
                <select name="XiD" id="XiD">
                  <option value="Blank" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
                  <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
                  <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
                  <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
                  </select>
                </span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Category 2:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="Category" id="Category" value="SMP_Backend" disabled="disabled" />                <input type="hidden" name="Category2" id="Category2" value="SMP_Backend" />    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Category 3:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2"><label for="Category3"></label>
                <select name="Category3" id="Category3">
          <option value="Blank" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>      
          <option value="Pending Request">Pending Request</option>
          <option value="Validation Error | Aging">Validation Error|Aging</option>
          <option value="Validation Error | RCM">Validation Error|RCM</option>
          <option value="Validation Error | Lost Stolen">Validation Error|Lost Stolen</option>
          </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Status:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2"><input name="Status1" type="text" id="Status1" value="Resolved" disabled="disabled" />
                 <input name="Status" type="hidden" id="Status" value="Resolved" /> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Severity:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="SeverityX" id="SeverityX" value="5" size="5" disabled="disabled"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="Severity" id="Severity" value="5" size="5" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Ban Type:</strong></td>
              <td colspan="2"><span style="font-size:12px">
                <input type="text" name="BanType2" id="BanType2" value="I" size="5" disabled="disabled"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="BanType" id="BanType" value="I" size="5" />
              </span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Phone No.:</strong></td>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Create Date:</strong></td>
              <td style="display:none" >RemedyTicketNo</td>
            </tr>
```

//here are my textareas:

```
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px"><textarea name="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" cols="15" rows="5"></textarea></td>
              <td><textarea name="Createdate" id="Createdate" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea></td>
              <td style="display:none"><textarea type=hidden name="RemedyTicketNo" id="RemedyTicketNo" cols="15" rows="5"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:12px">&nbsp;</td>
              <td colspan="2"><span style="font-size:12px">
                <input name="DBLoad" type="submit" id="DBLoad" value="DB Load" />
              </span></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form></td>
```

Comment: i cant get it what you want do exactly?

Comment: i am trying to insert into db, values are coming from 8 textfields and 3 textareas. im in the process of combining all values coming from textfields and textareas but just cant seem to make it work. so what should happen is each line from my textarea would correspond to my 8 textfields.

Comment: why you using text area for phone number?

Comment: that is because we need to upload multiple phone numbers to db...

Comment: have you checked what error you are getting? there might be error in your sql insert statement

Comment: am not getting any error...just a white page when i refresh my browser...

Comment: can you post your html form code? i will make proper

Comment: add this line to your code `error_reporting(E_ALL);` for displaying error

Comment: im getting undefine index for $Category2 = $_POST['Category2'];    $Category3 = $_POST['Category3'];$Status = $_POST['Status'];    $Date = $_POST['Date'];$Severity = $_POST['Severity'];$BanType = $_POST['BanType'];$XiD = $_POST['XiD'];$Ticket = $_POST['Ticket']; and Undefined offset in here: $values[] = "('{$PhoneNumber[$index]}', '{$Createdate[$index]}', '{$RemedyTicketNo[$index]}')";

Comment: i think my main issue here is how to combine values from textareas and textfields prior to INSERTing to db...just cant get it to worked...

Comment: but which is text area field tell me

Comment: please check my html code above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i edited your code

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['DBLoad']))
    {
        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        $dbs=mysql_select_db('test',$con);

        //print_r($_POST);
        //die();
        $Category2 = $_POST['Category2'];
        $Category3 = $_POST['Category3'];
        $Status = $_POST['Status'];
        $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        $Severity = $_POST['Severity'];
        $BanType = $_POST['BanType'];
        $XiD = $_POST['XiD'];
        $Ticket = $_POST['Ticket'];

        //Process the input textareas into arrays
        $PhoneNumber = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode("\r\n", $_POST['PhoneNumber']));
        $Createdate = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode("\r\n", $_POST['Createdate']));
        $RemedyTicketNo = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode("\r\n", $_POST['PhoneNumber']));
       //Determine the values with the least amoutn of elements
      $min_count = min(count($PhoneNumber), count($Createdate), count($RemedyTicketNo));

        //Create array to hold INSERT values
        $values = array();

        //Create the INSERT values
        for($index=0; $index<$min_count; $index++)
        {
        $values[$index] = "('{$PhoneNumber[$index]}', '{$Createdate[$index]}', '{$RemedyTicketNo[$index]}')";   
        }

        if (isset($RemedyTicketNo)) 
        {
     $sql="INSERT into tbl_main (phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name) 
            VALUES (\"" . implode (', ', $values) ."\", '".$Category2."', '".$Category3."', '".$Status."', '".$Date."','".$Date."','".$Severity."', '".$BanType."', '".$XiD."') ";
       $result=mysql_query($sql);

       header("Location: smp_backend_test.php");
        }
    }else
    {
    ?>
    <td colspan="2"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
              <table width="435" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="115"><div align="left" style="font-size:12px"></div></td>
                  <td width="167" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td width="139" align="right"><input type="reset" name="Clear" id="Clear" value="Clear" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="24" style="font-size:12px"><strong>Ticket Source:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><select name="Ticket" id="Ticket">
                    <option value="tickettracker.php">Please select...</option>
                    <option value="wireless_new.php">Wireless - Remedy</option>
                    <option value="smp_backend_test.php" selected="selected">SMP - Backend</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="24" style="font-size:12px"><strong>Date:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <label for="datepickerID"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="Date" id="Date" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>XiD, Name:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><span style="font-size:12px">
                    <select name="XiD" id="XiD">
                      <option value="Blank" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
                      <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
                      <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
                      <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
                      </select>
                    </span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Category 2:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="Category" id="Category" value="SMP_Backend" disabled="disabled" />                <input type="hidden" name="Category2" id="Category2" value="SMP_Backend" />    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Category 3:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><label for="Category3"></label>
                    <select name="Category3" id="Category3">
              <option value="Blank" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>      
              <option value="Pending Request">Pending Request</option>
              <option value="Validation Error | Aging">Validation Error|Aging</option>
              <option value="Validation Error | RCM">Validation Error|RCM</option>
              <option value="Validation Error | Lost Stolen">Validation Error|Lost Stolen</option>
              </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Status:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><input name="Status1" type="text" id="Status1" value="Resolved" disabled="disabled" />
                     <input name="Status" type="hidden" id="Status" value="Resolved" /> 
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Severity:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="SeverityX" id="SeverityX" value="5" size="5" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Severity" id="Severity" value="5" size="5" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Ban Type:</strong></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><span style="font-size:12px">
                    <input type="text" name="BanType2" id="BanType2" value="I" size="5" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="BanType" id="BanType" value="I" size="5" />
                  </span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Phone No.:</strong></td>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><strong>Create Date:</strong></td>
                  <td style="display:none" >RemedyTicketNo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px"><textarea name="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" cols="15" rows="5"></textarea></td>
                  <td><textarea name="Createdate" id="Createdate" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea></td>
                  <td style="display:none"><textarea type=hidden name="RemedyTicketNo" id="RemedyTicketNo" cols="15" rows="5"></textarea>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:12px">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td colspan="2"><span style="font-size:12px">
                    <input name="DBLoad" type="submit" id="DBLoad" value="DB Load" />
                  </span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form></td>



    <?php }?>
```

for simply checking validation for null follow the code and you should check more  it just a sample how you can do with javascript you can do it with Jquery too

```
 function validateDBLoad () {
        var xid=document.getElementById('XiD').value;
        var PhoneNumber=document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value;
        var Status=document.getElementById('Status').value;
        var Category2=document.getElementById('Category2').value;
        var Category3=document.getElementById('Category3').value;
        var Createdate=document.getElementById('Createdate').value;
        var Severity=document.getElementById('Severity').value;
        var BanType=document.getElementById('BanType').value;


         if((xid=="Blank") || (PhoneNumber=="") || (Category2) || (Category3=="Blank") || (Status=="") || (Createdate=="") || (Severity=="") || (document.form1.BanType.value=="")) { alert('Please fill up all the fields..'); return false; } else { alert('Ticket upload Successful.'); return true; } }
```

and make your table as follow

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_main` (
  `ars_no` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phone_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `trouble_type_priority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ban_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `resolved_date` date NOT NULL,
  `employee_id_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ars_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Comment: and modify your insert query according to your need i didnt changed anything in that might be that have error

Comment: you can check output using `echo die()`

Comment: thanks for updating my code...main page is loading now...ive tried uploading some data...i got the message that it was successful but it was really not in the db...i think i also have issues with my INSERT code...

Comment: im actually getting this sample error: "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\SMP_backend_test.php on line 35" after i got the message upload successful, this is my line 35: $values[] = "('{$PhoneNumber[$index]}', '{$Createdate[$index]}', '{$RemedyTicketNo[$index]}')";

Comment: make your line `$values[$index] = "('{$PhoneNumber[$index]}', '{$Createdate[$index]}', '{$RemedyTicketNo[$index]}')` and i told you that you have error in insert

Comment: you told me to fix only textarea and textfield combination so i did only that :)

Comment: thanks for extending ur help on this...all is good now...except that data is not uploading to db...im getting a message that upload was successful but its not in the db when i checked it...might be related to my INSERT statement and form validator...not sure though...

Comment: oh its ok.. if you get any error tell me i will try to help you

Comment: `if (isset($RemedyTicketNo)) 
    {
  $sql="INSERT into tbl_main (ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name) 
        VALUES ('" . implode (', ', $values) ."', '".$Category2."', '".$Category3."', '".$Status."', '".$Date."', '".$Severity."', '".$BanType."', '".$XiD."') ";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    header("Location: smp_backend_test.php");`

Comment: im kinda at lost here...ive tried to debug the code using the following: if (!$result) {die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); and its not giving any error...it looks like its functioning properly but really not INSERTing the data to db...pls look at my code...ive edited it again...but same thing...

Comment: copy and past my whole code i have edited to echo query then copy it and run directly in to database and tell me what error you are getting

Comment: i think i know where the problem is now...here is what it echoed after doing what u suggested:

Comment: `INSERT into tbl_main (ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name) VALUES ('('1', '1', '1'), ('2', '2', '2')', 'SMP_Backend', 'Pending Request', 'Resolved', '2013-04-28', '5', 'I', 'AAA')`

Comment: so what my code is doing is that its INSERTing the array values of my textareas on its own and not associating the first line value to the values of my textfileds, here's what its supposed to be doing:

Comment: `INSERT into tbl_main (ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name) 
 VALUES ('('1', '1', '1', 'SMP_Backend', 'Pending Request', 'Resolved', '2013-04-28', '5', 'I', 'AAA'), ('2', '2', '2', 'SMP_Backend', 'Pending Request', 'Resolved', '2013-04-28', '5', 'I', 'AAA')')`

Comment: can u help me in editing my code...just dont know how to make it work...:(

Comment: yes i will help but now for some time i am busy get back to you after some time

Comment: ive found a code that performs what i want, ive set the 
`$values[] = "('$RemedyTicketNo[$index]','$PhoneNumber[$index]','$Createdate[$index]',
    '$Category2','$Category3','$Status','$Date','$Severity','$BanType','$XiD')";` and SQL to: `$sql="INSERT into tbl_main
 (ars_no,phone_number,create_date,category_1,category_2,status,resolved_date,trouble_type_priority,ban_type,employee_id_name)
 VALUES " . implode (',',$values);
   die();
    $result=mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: ive echoed the SQL statement and use MySQL to directly insert the echoed SQL statement and it worked, it updated db but when i use the browser, its not updating the db...i guess this has something to do with my form validator already...below is the SQL query that i tried:

Comment: `INSERT into tbl_main (ars_no,phone_number,create_date,category_1,category_2,status,resolved_date,trouble_type_priority,ban_type,employee_id_name) 
VALUES ('test1','test1','test1', 'SMP_Backend','Pending Request','Resolved','2013-04-29','5','I','AAA'),('test2','test2','test2', 'SMP_Backend','Pending Request','Resolved','2013-04-29','5','I','AAA')`

Comment: can u just help me check if my form validator is correct and if not pls advise as to how i can correct it

Comment: `function validateDBLoad ()
 {
 if((document.form1.XiD.value=="Blank") || (document.form1.PhoneNumber.value=="") || (document.form1.Category2.value=="") || (document.form1.Category3.value=="Blank") || (document.form1.Status.value=="Blank") || (document.form1.Createdate.value=="") || (document.form1.Severity.value=="") || (document.form1.BanType.value=="") || (document.form1.Date.value==""))
    {
     alert('Please fill up all the fields..');
     return false;
    }
    else
    {
     alert('Ticket upload Successful.');
     return true;
    }
   }`

Comment: can you provide me your `tbl_main` formate so i can check here whats the problem is, you can do it with export

Comment: Table structure for table `tbl_main`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_main` (
  `ars_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `trouble_type_priority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ban_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `resolved_date` date NOT NULL,
  `employee_id_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ars_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: hi, do we have some sort of array validation...like the textareas in my code...is it enough to validate once like what u have in the validator that u created or how can we validate per line in my textareas?

Comment: for that you have to create function

Comment: i got the problem in your query, what you want to store in resolve date and ars_no?

Comment: i have edited the answer just copy and past all its working fully